# How to create a programming language in Python

Tags: python, programming-languages

I have seen a lot of tutorials for making a programming language, but very few for writing one in Python. I would like to know how to (relatively easily) create a programming language using Python.

Comment: The same as in any other language. Seriously if you know how to implement a compiler (or interpreter) in any language and you know how to program python, you know how to implement a compiler in python.

Comment: There are good tools for C/C++ for parsing your language: [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) and [flex](http://flex.sourceforge.net/) can help a lot. I have no idea if such tools exist for python as well.

Comment: If your goal is to "relatively easily create a programming language," you should stop now.  There are plenty of languages already--find one that is close enough--this will be much easier.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to make a parser, compiler, or interpreter. I tried to make one in Python and it worked, but I couldn't get structures such as functions, objects, and methods working. @JohnZwinck I am doing this so I can learn about programming languages. What I mean by relatively easily is not creating one totally from scratch, if that's possible

Comment: If you're leaning off of the work from an existing language, it'd be better to add libraries to it (to give it increased functionality), instead of adding new grammar and syntax to it.

Comment: @Makoto What I mean is using a parser generator, not completely from scratch, but if I had to I would do it from scratch.

Comment: @elijaheac:  In that case, you'd be fine with [LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)).

Comment: *"The problem is I don't know how to make a parser, compiler, or interpreter."* You may be looking for an advanced CS course at a university instead of an answer on Stack Overflow. "How do I create a programming language" isn't a question that can be answered in a format smaller than a very heavy textbook.

Comment: I have seen parsers written easily in Python. They do not have to be an 'advanced CS course at a university'

Comment: @JohnZwinck Stop being a nay-sayer. Nothing was wrong with the Model-T, yet we got catalogs of vehicles with different purposes today. And out of it, we got trucks, tanks, race cars, tractors, garbage trucks, clown cars, etc. All have a specific purpose. And as of right now, Jonathan Blow is proposing a new programming language that counters your argument.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/marciok/Mu#writing-your-own-programming-language

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Imagine your language.  What do you want it to look like?  What features should it have?
2. Think of an existing language that is as similar as possible to your desired language.  It's fine if the keywords are all different, but if you decided to make Python you wouldn't start with Lisp because the structures are fundamentally very different.
3. Find an existing grammar for the language you chose in step 2.  I'd look here: http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html .  If you can't find one, do step 2 again.
4. Using ANTLR (or whatever parser generator understands the grammar you found in step 3), build a Python module that understands the language you chose in step 2.  ANTLR has some level of support for a Python "target" (meaning that the parser code will be in Python, as opposed to making a parser that understands the Python language).  If you get stuck with parser code in C (which you may), write Python bindings for it (probably easiest using Boost Python, but you could use the Python C API directly if you are pretty familiar with both C and Python).
5. Start making modifications (in small steps at first) to the grammar from step 3 to make it more like the language you designed in step 1.

Do these things carefully and deliberately, and after a few days of work you may have a halfway-decent parser for your language.  Then you'll need to consume the output of the parser (if using ANTLR, consider using the Abstract Syntax Trees, or ASTs, that it can generate for you).  Then you'll need to convert the parsed syntax into a target language, such as x86 assembly or some intermediate bytecode such as the one used by Java, Lua, Microsoft .NET, or whatever.

Good luck, and be forewarned: this process will take a long time to do right.

Answer (score 22):

Not sure what you mean by "creating a programming language". But I think you might like to read Peter Norvig's excellent article [(How to Write a (Lisp) Interpreter (in Python))](http://norvig.com/lispy.html). This shows how you can build a Lisp interpreter in only [90 lines of Python](http://norvig.com/lis.py)!

Once you understood that, try [(An ((Even Better) Lisp) Interpreter (in Python))](http://norvig.com/lispy2.html).

Comment: Works fine on my PC. Which Python version are you using (it assumes Python 2.7, I think)?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'. I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows.

Comment: @elijaheac: Can't reproduce this here (Python 2.7.2 on Win x64). Did you `import lis` and then `lis.repl()`?

Comment: I did it in a 'if __name__ == "__main__":' block. Should I create        a new file and import it instead?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. What does `if name == '__main__':` have to do with it and what did you put in there? `lis.py` is a Lisp interpreter, so it runs interactively.